# How do I include a JSTL 1.2 implementation through Maven?

Tags: maven, jstl

I'm getting a strange error with maven when trying to use JSTL:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I think that this is because it's not a concrete implementation. Seems like there is a concrete implementation in Glassfish, but I have no idea how to include it.

The error I'm getting is like:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport
```

OR

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If the application server you use already provides a JSTL implementation it should be sufficient to add `<scope>provided</scope>` to your definition, otherwise you could try and add

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Well, maven was happy with that. Thanks for the answer. Tomcat said no though :(

Comment: Which alternative did you try? Does the second actually include the jstl-impl jar in your application? If Tomcat was unhappy with the first one, I'd guess that it doesn't provide a jstl implementation. Could you post any erroro message that looks relevant?