# Error when including jstl dependency in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, jstl

In Eclipse, Maven is showing a dependency problem in `pom.xml`:

[image]

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dependency in `pom.xml` to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also want to take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6873878).